# FFmpeg drawtext's fontfile unable to load

Tags: ffmpeg

I have This Parisienne-type Font file and I want to write on a gif using that font but the output font is never Parisienne, it always comes out as normal Arial

the command

```
ffmpeg -i C:\Users\1997\www\post2\css\back2.gif -vf "drawtext=fontfile='C\:\\Windows\\Fonts\\2.ttf':text='Darbuka 70':fontcolor=#5c391685:fontsize=160::x=(w-text_w)/2:y=20" C:\Users\1997\www\post2\css\output.mp4
```

This is how the font file looks:
[image]

the output:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely due to not having enough escape characters (`\`). You need one for FFmpeg and double them for shell. So, try

```
fontfile='C\\\\:/Windows/Fonts/2.ttf'
```

Four `\`'s worked when I tested in Python, but if it doesn't add/subtract a pair at a time to see which works for you.

Last, if you want to see if `fontfile` option is set properly or not, add `-loglevel debug` option and look in the log for a line like:

```
[Parsed_drawtext_2 @ 0000015e54962a80] Setting 'fontfile' to value 'C:/Windows/Fonts/2.ttf'
```

If it's not properly escaped, you'd see a log like:

```
[Parsed_drawtext_2 @ 000001c010782440] Setting 'fontfile' to value 'C'
[Parsed_drawtext_2 @ 000001c010782440] Setting 'text' to value '/Windows/Fonts/2.ttf'
```

P.S., I cheated and used `/` for directory separator. If you want to use `\`, the same rule applies. You need a several `\`'s for each `\`. See [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Notes-on-filtergraph-escaping)